# php display and total pricing on same page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have been searching for a way to add up the total sum of radio buttons and echo it that total on the same page in php. Is there a way to do this? I have included an image of what I am looking at.

Here is code that I have come up with so far:

**PHP**

```
<?php
$prod1 = "10";
$prod2 = "20";
$prod3 = "30";
?>


<form action="">
<input type="radio" name="prod1" value="<?=$prod1?>">$10 product 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="prod2" value="<?=$prod2?>">$20 product 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="prod3" value="<?=$prod3?>">$30 product 3
</form>

<!-- This is where the total shows live upon radio check -->
<?php
echo ="$total"
?>
```

I am new so it will not post an image, here is a link to my image:

[image]

Comment: You can update a part of the page using Javascript or JQuery.  The PHP would already be rendered and would not update

Comment: Do you mean you want a total to change when the user selects another option? Or do you mean you want it to show after the user posts the form?

Comment: Do you want to the total to display as "$60"  or do you want it to be $10 if prod1 is selected, $20 is prod2 is selected, $30 if prod3 is selected?   or should they be able to choose a combination of products?

Comment: BTW you're using radio buttons - the user will never be able to uncheck them.

Comment: thanks. so no way to do this with PHP? I know that databases can add it, I was looking for a simple same page PHP

Comment: @Popnoodles - yes I want it to change the total when the user selects the options - live and on the same page

Comment: @greg_diesel - yes, as the radio is selected it will show it and combine it if more than one product is selected.

Comment: @Popnoodles - sorry, meant to do check boxes, just put in radios as a habit

Comment: @Popnoodles - thanks for adding the image - it would not let me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/6xmjhx7y/)

You need an element where the total is going to be, and a way of identifying those inputs. I've used `input` which isn't very specific; You may want to change this if you have more going on in that form.

I bound `change` to the form (which I gave the id `products`) because the change events made on the inputs will bubble up to the form, and we need to search the whole form for all the inputs so it made sense not to have to traverse, which we'd need to do if the function was bound to the input fields.

Then simply, on change of something in the form, add up the values of the checked elements. `parseFloat()` is used because the values are strings and you'd end up with "102030" where you really wanted "60".

HTML

```
<form action="" id="products">
    <label><input type="radio" name="prod1" value="10" />$10 product 1</label>
    <br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="prod2" value="20" />$20 product 2</label>
    <br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="prod3" value="30" />$30 product 3</label>
</form>

<p>Total $<span id="total">0</span></p>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('#products').on('change', function(){
        var total = 0;
        $(this).find('input:checked').each(function(){
            total += parseFloat($(this).val());
        });
        $('#total').text(total);
    });
});
```

By the way, if the user is supposed to be able to uncheck these options, you need to use `<input type="checkbox" ...`

Comment: thanks. this will work. the only downside is that if the user has javascript disabled, but how many users really disable js

Comment: If you're concerned about that then hide the total bit and show it with JS.

Comment: i hate to ask, but how would I add an input to this? Say if I put in 20 into the input, it would add 20 to the total. I have tried, but cant figure it out. thanks in advance

Comment: The input wouldn't be checked, but it would be type text, so you'd want to search for those too `$('input:checked, input:text').each..`

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I ended up doing this, it works as well.  http://jsfiddle.net/uds18z3v/

Comment: Great. You could do it in fewer lines. but there's nothing wrong with it.